# Usage of "do not " vs "does not"

Tags: grammar, differences, sentence, do

I am trying to understand the grammar behind using "do not" vs "does not".

Consider the following sentences.

1a. The way items are added to the cart **does not** guarantee an order. *vs*

1b. The way items are added to the cart **do not** guarantee an order.

2a. We will skip the entries that **do not** match *vs*

2b. We will skip the entries that **does not** match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Does' is only used in singular, third person. In other cases, 'do' is used. (The addition of 'not' does not matter.)

Therefore, **1a.** and **2a.** are correct. In the first sentence, 'the way' is the subject - hence the singular form ('does') is used. In the second sentence, 'the entries' is plural so you need the plural form 'do'.

Comment: As Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, What was your comment in reference to?

Comment: @Pacerier This question is not suitable for ELU, not because it is not important to know the grammar involved, but because that grammar is very basic.

Comment: Aren't basics important enough to be asked here? Stackoverflow sounds too arrogant at times.

BTW google led me here when I searched 'do' vs 'does'.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "do" and "does" auxiliary verbs depend on two factors; 1st is Subject and 2nd is tense ( only present simple tense). If Subject be third person singular number then aux.verb will be "does" and for other person and number it will always be "do".